# Is it possible to use a dataPattern in zoomBandChart?

Tags: lightningchart

I'm trying currently to add a zoomBandChart to my dashBoard. The chart that the zoomBandChart will be displaying, has the following dataPattern enabled:

```
    dataPattern: {
      pattern: 'ProgressiveX',
      regularProgressiveStep: false,
      allowDataGrouping: true,
    },
```

I'm using this chart to show large amounts of data (0.1ms interval points, loaded up to two weeks). The chart itself works fine, but when adding the zoomBandChart, the performance drops significantly. It seems to me, that the zoomBandChart does not use any dataPattern settings, which means, that it is trying to show all the data without any dataGrouping.

In my case, it is not neccesary to show the full graph in the zoomBandChart, a rough approximation would be enough, is there maybe some way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems that there is no such option available.

However, this is a very valid point and I believe we can make it happen in a future version release.

Probably it will work out of the box, without the user having to add some code, etc. (internally the Zoom Band Chart will just copy the data pattern of the source Line Series).

Comment: Awesome! Do you have maybe some kind of roadmap where it would be possible to track future releases?

Comment: At this time, not particularly. The next version release will happen in the coming few months.

Comment: New version releases are paired with dedicated content on our website lightningchart.com, we intend to disclose information about what to expect in future versions, etc. there. Also, the changelog of the released version will be released so you can check if your issue is resolved there.

Comment: This has been now implemented and will be released in v4.0.0 early 2023. It really is a massive performance improvement when there is a lot of data points (>1 million). So thank you for opening the question and for your patience...